# c# logic error in a while-loop entering condition

Tags: c#, syntax

I have some weird logic stuff going on.

```
x=false;
```

This one *does not* work:

```
while (R2.TS("a") && R2.TL("b") && (s=R2.SL().Trim()).Length > 0) 
{
    x=true;
}
```

result: x=false;

This one *does* work:

```
while (R2.TS("a") && R2.TL("b")) 
{
    if((s=R2.SL().Trim()).Length > 0) 
    {
        x=true;
    }
}
```

result: x=true;

Also, maybe it helps to know that those functions return true only if executed in right order, like R2.TS("a") then R2.TL("b") and then ((s=R2.SL().Trim()).Length > 0).

input is the same, but something is surely wrong here. Any ideas ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What's the error that you get?

Comment: As you can see it dosnt turn x to true, while theoretically it should. And i dont get any errors.

Comment: Your title suggests that this is a compile time error, but your comment suggests that this is a runtime error. Please clarify.

Comment: I'm honestly more concerned about the poorly named variables at this point.

Comment: I think he means the result of the first bit of spaghetti code is x not being set to true where with the second bit of spaghette is is set to true.

Comment: Without knowing what your inputs are -- especially with your assignment in an comparison, which is just like, why would you do that --  I'd suggest you write up a table of your logic.

Comment: I have no idea if this is a compiler or runtime error.

Comment: -1: Not knowing what "syntax error" is and not even trying to find out will limit your ability to get good answers. Consider using a search engine to find out, but if you are banned on all - Wikipedia is generally good starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_error

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I know well what syntax error is, and your comment dosn't help my problem at all.

Comment: Where is the syntax error ? What do TL / TS / SL do, do they modify R2 ?

Comment: @JulienCh. yes, they do modify it, but that should not matter, because logicaly they should do it same way in both cases.

Comment: @RaslyWalker But the number of loops might not...

Comment: @JulienCh. I wish, but as a fact those numbers are the same too.

Comment: @RaslyWalker, as far as I can tell there is at least 1 loop in the second case and strictly 0 loop in the first. What tells us there isn't 2, 3,... or 100 loops in the second case ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the loops do two different things.

I think you mean a logic error, not a syntax error.  Syntax error means it won't compile.  Logic error means it doesn't do what you expect.

The first one will terminate if the `R2.SL()` expression is false.  At least the first time round, `(s=R2.SL().Trim()).Length > 0` must necessarily be false, so loop 1 terminates and `x` is never set to true.  That is the only way you would get a difference between your two loops, all other conditions being the same.

In loop 2, intermediate values for `R2.SL()` isn't a problem, provided the other loop conditions remain true.  When `(s=R2.SL().Trim()).Length > 0` evaluates to true, `x` will be set.

Answer (score 1):

Use the debugger luke. There is little point us trying to work out why this doesn't give you the result you want. It is better for you to work that out with some help. Click on the first line and push F9. It should turn red. Run your program and it will stop at this line. You can then hover over different variables to see which ones have which values. Then push F11 to step forward through your program.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case have three conditions to which R2 has to comply namely
R2.TS("a") AND R2.TL("b") AND (s=R2.SL().Trim()).Length > 0), before you will enter the loop and return the value of x

In the 2nd case you only have two conditions to which R2 has to comply namely
R2.TS("a") AND R2.TL("b") and after the loop is entered, you have a new condition before the x value is returned.

They probably both work, but in the first case, you don't supply data which complies to the requirements of the loop.

Answer (score -1):

It may be connected with && and || operations. They are shortaned. It means, that operations are looked continuously utill the first `false` occurs in the condition.

Because of shortaned operations you get 2 different cycles, which have different logics. Use the 2 cycle type. It's more correct.

Comment: I don't think this explains it. The only real difference between the two cases that the first loop terminates earlier.

Comment: @ZongLi: Yes, it terminates earlier. That must be the problem. Because if `(s=R2.SL().Trim()).Length > 0 ` results false in the first cycle, it will exit. If there is an if in the body of the cycle, then it will terminate only when `R2.TS("a") && R2.TL("b")` result `false`. It's the only reason. The difference between 2 codes is only this, so there may not be another explanation.

Comment: Yes, that is why i dont get it, input is identical, but still in first case it dosnt reach the x.

Comment: @RaslyWalker: it's not a good style to write like it is writen in the first cycle. It also leads to such errors.